# how to disable scrolling in index.html not the other pages

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to disable the scrolling option in my index.html not the other pages.

I have tried to hide it but thats not what i whant.

I have this in my css but it only hides the scrollbar:

```
body {background: rgba(169,3,41,1); background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109,0,25,1))); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=1 ); **overflow: hidden** }
```

I also tride this:

```
body {background: rgba(169,3,41,1);
```

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109,0,25,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=1 );
position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

But this make my background collor dissapear and applys to all my pages...

Comment: I would also be happy if i can change the height of my index.html this way scrolling woudnt be possible yes?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far. your question is way too broad. edit your question and add your relevant html/css and what you have tried so far

Comment: you want to disable scroll on page

Answer (score 0):

overflow-y:hidden; /* Use this for hiding the Vertical scroll */

overflow-x:auto; /* Use this to show Horizontal scroll */

example :

```
html, body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: note that overflow-x/y are css3 features and will not work in older browsers. + OP said that hiding is not his intention.

Comment: come on ! in 5 days we will be on 2015 !! 99.9999999% of people use recent browser ! who use ie6 in 2014 ????????

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to stop Scroll by `CSS3`

```
    body
    {
        position: fixed; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
background: rgba(169,3,41,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109,0,25,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=1 );
**overflow: hidden**
    }
```

Comment: This work but my background collor dissapears... and this happens to all my pages i only whant the index

Comment: you post this code to page you want to disable scroll try my code made some changes

Comment: what i meant was that your code does the same thing as i written above. This makes my background dissapear and dissable the scrollinbar in all my pages. I only whant to lock the scrollingbar in my index.html page.

Comment: post your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and save and copy saved link and post your copied link here only then i can solve only with CSS code i can't find solve your problem